# pressing @ in the keyboard gives " (and # gives £ ) in mint16

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard

Hello I am using mint16(cinnamon). When I try to write @ it shows ". That is, key functioning of these two keys has got swapped somehow. Can someone please suggest a way to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Sounds like your keyboard layout is set to English - UK.

Comment: This would be even easier to answer if you told us which key is supposed to print `@`. Is it shift+2 or is it a dedicated key above the Shift?

Answer (score 1):

When installing your mint system, you did choose the wrong keyboard layout. (But you did not write which country you live and what kind of keyboard you have.)

You probably want to fix this by changing you current keyboard mapping which on cinnamon is unfortunately [a bit unintuitive](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/2142). Look for "region" in the preferences.